# Errors when running the vhdl code

Tags: vhdl

I'm running a VHDL code however i faced errors at the port map line when compiling. What is the problem and how do I solve it.

The error is saying:

> Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at DU.vhd(52) near text "port";  expecting "(", or "'", or "."

My code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.all;

entity DU is
    port(
    Clk     : in std_logic;
    state   : in std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);     
    Input   : in std_logic_vector (63 downto 0);
    De_out,En_out       : out std_logic_vector (63 downto 0)
    );
end DU;

architecture result of DU is
signal en_data1,en_data2    : std_logic_vector (63 downto 0);
signal de_data1,de_data2    : std_logic_vector (63 downto 0);
signal en_sum,de_sum        : std_logic_vector (31 downto 0):=x"00000000";
signal k0,k1,k2,k3,delta    : std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);

component encoder
port(
    k0,k1,k2,k3,delta   : in std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
    En_In   : in std_logic_vector (63 downto 0);
    En_Out  : out std_logic_vector (63 downto 0)
);
end component;

component decoder
port(
    k0,k1,k2,k3,delta   : in std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
    Dec_In  : in std_logic_vector (63 downto 0);
    Dec_Out : out std_logic_vector (63 downto 0)
);
end component;


begin
    process(state,Clk)
    begin
    k0 <= x"CBE6160F";
    k1 <= x"12345678";
    k2 <= x"FC189540";
    k3 <= x"00AB7655";
    delta <= x"9E3779B9";

    if(rising_edge(Clk)) then
        if state(0) = '1' then
            en_data1 <= Input;
            en_sum <= en_sum + delta;
            En_Out <= Input;
        elsif state(1) = '1' then
            encryption : encoder port map (k0,k1,k2,k3,en_sum,en_data1,en_data2);
            En_Out <= en_data2;
            en_data1 <= en_data2;
            en_sum <= en_sum + delta;
        elsif state(2) = '1' then
            de_data1 <= en_data2;
            de_sum <= en_sum;
            De_Out <= de_data1;
        elsif state(3) = '1' then
            decryption : decoder port map (k0,k1,k2,k3,de_sum,de_data1,de_data2);
            De_Out <= de_data2;
            de_data1 <= de_data2;
            de_sum <= de_sum - delta;
        end if;
    end if;
    end process;

end result;
```

Comment: [why error near text "port"; expecting - Altera Forums](https://www.alteraforum.com/forum/showthread.php?t=39959)

Comment: [VHDL: port map in process error](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/183010/vhdl-port-map-in-process-error) (by our own scary_jeff)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot instantiate an entity inside a process.

```
encryption : encoder port map (k0,k1,k2,k3,en_sum,en_data1,en_data2);
```

This needs to be done outside your process, with the inputs connected regardless of state. You can then multiplex the outputs according to which state you are in.